# Mysql_fetch_array issue

Tags: php, mysql

How to display all info from an order in the same table ?
So i have in my database like this

```
id  id_transaction  id_product  product type    nr_buc  user    phone   adress  status  date_order
1   1   1   Lamb Doner Kebab    small   1   Adrian Nicolae Cozma    phone   adress  0   2015-03-09 10:19:09
2   1   13  Cheeseburger    large   3   Adrian Nicolae Cozma    phone   adress  0   2015-03-09 10:19:09
3   1   33  330ml Cans  standard    4   Adrian Nicolae Cozma    phone   adress  0   2015-03-09 10:19:09 
4   2   66  Portion of Fresh Nan Bread  standard    1   Nicolae C.  phone   Home    0   2015-03-09 10:19:09
5   2   39  Red bull    standard    1   Nicolae C.  phone   Home    0   2015-03-09 10:19:09
```

I want to display tables for each id_transaction with the products below, when there are no products, search for next id_transactions and fetch products and place them in another table .

In this moment my code creates tables*(number of products) with the same info and i don't know what's the mistake . Please help me .

```
<h1>Orders</h1>

                <?php
                $sqlTranzactii = "SELECT id_transaction, DATE_FORMAT(date_order, '%d-%m-%Y') as data_tranzactie, user, nr_buc, phone, adress FROM orders WHERE status = 0";
                $resursaTranzactii = mysql_query($sqlTranzactii);
                while ($rowTranzactie = mysql_fetch_array($resursaTranzactii)) {
                    ?>

                    <form action="prelucrare_comenzi.php" method="post">
                        Order Date:
                        <b><?= $rowTranzactie['data_tranzactie'] ?></b>

                        <div class="tranzactie">
                            Buyer:
                            <b><?= $rowTranzactie['user'] ?></b><br />
                            Adress:
                            <?= $rowTranzactie['adress'] ?><br />
                            Phone contact:
                            <?= $rowTranzactie['phone'] ?>
                            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">     
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>no. of items</th>
                                        <th>Product</th>
                                        <th>Size</th>
                                        <th>Total</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <?php
                                $sqlCarti = "SELECT nr_buc, product, type FROM orders WHERE status = 0 and id_transaction=" . $rowTranzactie['id_transaction'] . "";
                                $resursaCarti = mysql_query($sqlCarti);
                                while ($rowCarte = mysql_fetch_array($resursaCarti)) {
                                    echo '<tr><th>'
                                    . $rowCarte['nr_buc'] . '</th>
                                  <th>
                                  ' . $rowCarte['product'] . '</th>
                                  <th>'
                                    . $rowCarte['type'] . '</th>';

                                    $total = $rowCarte['price'] * $rowCarte['nr_buc'];
                                    echo'<th>£' . $total . '</th>';
                                    $totalGeneral = $totalDeneral + $total;
                                }
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="3" align="right"> Total order price: </th>
                                    <th><?= $totalGeneral ?> £ </th>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_tranzactie" value="<?= $rowTranzactie['id'] ?>" />
                            <input type="submit" name="comanda_onorata" value="Comanda Onorata" />
                            <input type="submit" name="anuleaza_comanda" value="Anuleaza comanda" />
                        </div>
                    </form><br>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
```

Output : http://adicozma.herobo.com/img/orders.png

Comment: Do not use deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or pdo.

Comment: Any error message returning??

Comment: No error. It creates tables as many products has the id_order = ?? http://adicozma.herobo.com/img/orders.png